# Is there any option to query and get ARN of IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to query ARN of individual IAM policy. Tried below command as per AWS tech document but not getting correct output. 
Is this option --query available currently to fetch the ARN of policies? Is there any other command or option in CLI?

```
C:\Users\jijina\.aws>aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`]' --output text

Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`]
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`]
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`]
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`]
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`]
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`]
```

Comment: Are you trying something like this: `aws iam list-policies --region us-east-1 --output text --query 'Policies[?PolicyName==\`AdministratorAccess\`].Arn'`

Comment: Yes. But this command is not giving ARN output. Checked help for "aws iam list-policies". Its not showing --query option. Hence, is there any other way out in CLI to get ARN alone?

Comment: The command I shared should show the ARN. It did for me. Could you please share the output you receive when you run the command I shared?

Comment: Here is the output of command I executed.

C:\Users\jijina\.aws>aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.142 Python/3.7.3 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.132

C:\Users\jijina\.aws>aws iam list-policies --region us-east-1 --output text --query 'Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`].Arn'
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`].Arn
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`].Arn
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`].Arn
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`].Arn
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`].Arn
Policies[?PolicyName==`AdministratorAccess`].Arn

Comment: If you are running the command on Windows, some of the quotes need to change. Try `"` instead of `'` and play with the quotes around the string. If you keep playing, you'll get it to work. (And then let us know what you used!)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked :). Here is the command executed.


C:\Users\jijina\.aws>aws iam list-policies --region us-east-1 --output text --query "Policies[?PolicyName=='AdministratorAccess'].Arn"
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess